# How to capture bitmap image from video of camera gige industrial

Tags: video-capture

```
    private void BT_Chup_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PTB_Cam.Image = (Image)PTB_Cam.Image.Clone();
        Bitmap AnhChup = new Bitmap(PTB_Cam.Image);
        Bitmap AnhResize = new Bitmap(AnhChup, 350, 250);
        PTB_AnhChup.Image = AnhResize;
    }
```

when i run it, it says error at PTB_Cam.Image = (Image)PTB_Cam.Image.Clone();
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
How can I fix this, I'm not a programmer, I'm a mechatronics student working on a project, thank you very much